# Python regex for getting session and token

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I tried to get token and session from this string but I could not to parse by using python regex.
How can I do that? My problem is that "-" exists both in the link and token value. so I could not get the token and also session value from the string:

```
b'https://urlpart1-urlpart2-urlpart3\nusername@com\nMsrrkr.\nweb page opened\nTrying to login ...\ntoken: 125834b5-b6ed-4b37-ada7-12c2199003d2\nsession: MDdiZTEyNzAtZTE4ZS00MTY5LWFkYzgtN2QzZjI5ZjY0YWI1\n'
```

Comment: @DYZ is this for to get url ? but I need to get token and session?

Comment: Nevermind. Have you tried to split the string by line breaks? It's kind of obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nicely organized key:value data. Split the string into lines, then split each line by a semicolon, and build a dictionary:

```
parts = [x.split(":") for x in yourstring.decode().split('\n')]
values = {p[0]: p[1].strip() for p in parts if len(p)==2}
values['token']
values['session']
```

There is no need to use regex here.

Answer (score 1):

if you really need to use regexp you can do something like that:

```
import re
r='https://urlpart1-urlpart2-urlpart3\nusername@com\nMsrrkr.\nweb page opened\nTrying to login ...\ntoken: 125834b5-b6ed-4b37-ada7-12c2199003d2\nsession: MDdiZTEyNzAtZTE4ZS00MTY5LWFkYzgtN2QzZjI5ZjY0YWI1\n'

m = re.search("token:\s(\S+)\ssession:\s(\S+)\s", r)
print(m.group(1))
print(m.group(2))
```